# How to initialise onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android

I'm having some issues with the onSaveInstanceState, but it may be because I misunderstand how it works.

I have a Arraylist i want to save when I switch activities then restore when i come back.

so i have this method

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putStringArrayList("History", History);
```

and my onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        History = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("History");
    }

}
```

For some reason this loop is not being initliased

```
    if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        History = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("History");
    }
```

I'm pretty sure its soemthing fairly simple but I'm still quite new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply switching activities, it will stay 'alive' in the background (unless the OS decides to kill it off to free memory). [Read this article for more information on Activity state](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

In this case, `onCreate()` will not be called when the Activity resumes, as it has already been created and is simply been `onResume()`-ed.

You should look at another method of storing your `History` values such as in `SharedPreferences`, a database or in a persistent object on the application class instance (whatever suits your preference) in your `onPause()` method and restore those values in `onResume()`.

`onSavedInstanceState()` is used for when an activity is killed like in an orientation change or OS kill.

Comment: Oh ok i see although I have a new issue now it seems that SharedPreferences saves my values even when i close and restart my app. Any ideas how to reset the variables on each new run?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are a persistent storage across all instances of your app, so it is [working as designed](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). You could clear out your record in `SharedPreferences` when the app loads in the `onCreate()` method of your primary activity. Otherwise you could consider storing your array in a more volatile form such as in an object on your application class.

Comment: Ah yeah nice got it working :)

for anyone who has a similar issue here is a nice link that has a good Global class example code.

https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/defining-global-variables-in-android/